# Android: Fragments:calling another activity from List fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi iam playing with the korovyansk slideout sample app, am new to fragments, can someone tell how can i call a activity from a another fragment. when the list item  clicked it should trigger another activity

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { " First", " Second", " Third", " Fourth", " Fifth", " Sixth"}));
        getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        ((MenuActivity)getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something as simple as below

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent exampleIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Example.class);
    exampleIntent.putExtra("ARGS", Var);
    startActivity(exampleIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you pinto..that will do .